# Select data from table in Kumulos

Tags: android, kumulos

I am new to Kumulos development.

I want to get selected data from table of kumulos.

Like If user enter username and password i check from table that data exits or not.

But the issue is while checking data inserted in table and not giving me correct output.

While testing api in browser it works fine.

My code for select from table is below.

```
public void CallApiLogin(){


        final String Uname=editUname.getText().toString();
        final String pass=editPass.getText().toString();

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name", Uname);
        params.put("password",pass);

        Kumulos.call("user_register", params, new ResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void didCompleteWithResult(Object result) {
                // Do updates to UI/data models based on result

                ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> objects = (ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>>) result;
                for (LinkedHashMap<String, Object> item : objects) {
                    String name = (String) item.get("name");
                    String password = (String) item.get("password");

                    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(Uname) && password.equalsIgnoreCase(pass)){
                        Intent i=new Intent(Login.this,Home.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter valid username and password.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

Please suggest where i am going wrong as requested data inserted in table.

But i want that request data exist or not????

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours, I got solution.

Issue is creating api. In Kumulos you have to create different api.

**I was using api "user_register", Now i have create other api call "Select_user".**

This api works fine what the result i want.

I hope this question may help some other.